# Store and encrypt a password locally in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, password-protection

I need to develop a tool in C# which interacts with a SOAP webservice. The first operation of this webservice takes a username and password to login to the application. However that tool shall be run without user interaction when providing the user credentials.

This implies that the tool knows the username and password. What would be a more or less appropriate way of storing the encryped username and password either in the program code or in an external file?

Comment: Will this tool be running as a service inside IIS? There are some IIS specific options available to you too besides what the answers have already mentioned.

Comment: No, it is not planned to being run as a service in IIS. Just a simple command-line tool :-)

Comment: If a post helped you, please consider marking it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed need to store the password in some form, better encrypt it using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). AES is a proven algorithm which is not feasible to thwart at least until the next decade. See this SO link to find some examples of AES encryption in C#:

[Using AES encryption in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273452/using-aes-encryption-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The user shall not type the password. The tool needs access to the remote system without a user interaction.

Comment: okies. In that case, you can AES encrypt the password string before storing it. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would think about using the [DPAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756046/how-secure-is-protecteddata-protect-dpapi) There should be a machine specific algorithm. Which should ensure, that the data can only be decrypted on the machine on which it was encrypted.

In the linked post is also a good [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx#windataprotection-dpapi_topic04) linked

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
// Encrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. The result can be decrypted 

//  only by the same current user. 

return ProtectedData.Protect( data, s_aditionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
```

Answer (score 1):

The less appropriate way is to store your password in clear in a plain text in  text file or in registry  which  will  make your sensitive information accessible  to  everyone who gain  access as an admin
One of the best way to obfuscate the password  is to use this   [ProtectedData Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)
 here  an example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class DataProtectionSample
{
// Create byte array for additional entropy when using Protect method. 
    static byte [] s_aditionalEntropy = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 };

    public static void Main()
    {
// Create a simple byte array containing data to be encrypted. 

byte [] secret = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

//Encrypt the data. 
        byte [] encryptedSecret = Protect( secret );
        Console.WriteLine("The encrypted byte array is:");
        PrintValues(encryptedSecret);

// Decrypt the data and store in a byte array. 
        byte [] originalData = Unprotect( encryptedSecret );
        Console.WriteLine("{0}The original data is:", Environment.NewLine);
        PrintValues(originalData);

    }

    public static byte [] Protect( byte [] data )
    {
        try
        {
            // Encrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. The result can be decrypted 
            //  only by the same current user. 
            return ProtectedData.Protect( data, s_aditionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
        } 
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data was not encrypted. An error occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte [] Unprotect( byte [] data )
    {
        try
        {
            //Decrypt the data using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser. 
            return ProtectedData.Unprotect( data, s_aditionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
        } 
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data was not decrypted. An error occurred.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void PrintValues( Byte[] myArr )  
    {
          foreach ( Byte i in myArr )  
            {
                 Console.Write( "\t{0}", i );
             }
      Console.WriteLine();
     }

}
```